# My R plot of the F distribution doesn't seem right

Tags: r, data-visualization

In order to simulate two independent variables, so that $\beta=0$ in their linear regression model, I wrote the following code:

```r
    x <- 1:100
    fs <- c()
    for (i in 1:10^6) {
      ys <- rnorm(100,0,1)
      ybar <- mean(y)
      cs <- lm(y~x)$coefficients
      b0 <- cs[1]
      b1 <- cs[2]
      yhat <- x*b1+b0
      SST <- sum( (ys-ybar)^2 )
      SSE <- sum( (ys-yhat)^2 )
      SSR <- sum( (yhat-ybar)^2 )
      fs <- c(fs, SSR*(n-2)/SSE)
    }
```

and then to see how well this fits the theoretical distribution I plotted

```
    h <- hist(fs, prob=TRUE)
    y <- df(x,1,98)
    lines(x,y)
```

The plot of the "empirical" distribution, the histogram, looks about right.  But the plot of the theoretical F distribution doesn't display.  When I plot it by itself, the height of the distribution is much lower than the empirical distribution.  That makes it clear why it's not displaying, but then it seems like this isn't correctly plotting the F distribution.  However, every resource I found online about how to plot a distribution basically does it this way, so I'm not sure what I should do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your script with some minor modifications, and it worked for me:

```
x <- 1:100
n <- length(x)

fs <- c()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  ys <- rnorm(100,0,1)
  ybar <- mean(ys)
  cs <- lm(ys~x)$coefficients
  b0 <- cs[1]
  b1 <- cs[2]
  yhat <- x*b1+b0
  SST <- sum( (ys-ybar)^2 )
  SSE <- sum( (ys-yhat)^2 )
  SSR <- sum( (yhat-ybar)^2 )
  fs <- c(fs, SSR*(n-2)/SSE)
}

h <- hist(fs, prob=TRUE)
xx <- 1:100/10
y <- df(xx,1,98)
lines(xx, y, col="red")
```

(The modifications: Define `n`; replace some instances of `y` with `ys`; reduce the number of iterations; use a smaller range of `x`-values, and more closely spaced, for the theoretical F distribution.) The result:

[image]